# What is the worst case scenario for insertion sort O(n^2)?

Tags: language-agnostic, sorting

What is the worst case scenario for insertion sort `O(n^2)`?

it strikes me that if the array to be sorted is already sorted in reverse order then the first element is compared 0 times the second 1 time, the third 2 times and so on and so the total time should equal the `SUM {i=1->i=(n-1)} [n]` but that doesn't equal `n^2` (for example if `n=4` then that sum is `1+2+3=6`.

this [website](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aJ8tDswJq514J%3awww.cs.sunysb.edu/~bender/newpub/BenderFaMo06-librarysort.ps%20insertion%20sort%20O%28n%5E2%29&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=www.google.com) says its because each insertion takes O(n) and theres n of those so thats O(n^2). but why does each insertion take O(n), the first one doesn't so onlyl n-1 insertions could take O(n) but neither does the second one and so on. only the insertions towards infinity take O(n) to insert. (is it becuase theres an infinite number of elements with insirtion=O(n) and so the oens where insertion takes

Answer (score 5):

Your example is correct.

O(n²) means *proportional* to n² as *n* approaches infinity, *not* necessarily equal n² for all n.

More precisely, to show that f(n) and g(n) are proportional as n grows to infinity, you need to show

[\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = c http://www.texify.com/img/%5CLarge%5C%21%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7Bf%28n%29%7D%7Bg%28n%29%7D%20%3D%20c.gif](http://www.texify.com/img/%5CLarge%5C%21%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7Bf%28n%29%7D%7Bg%28n%29%7D%20%3D%20c.gif)

for some finite nonzero constant *c*. In this case, you get something like

[\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^2}{\left(\frac{n^2+n}{2}\right)} = 2 http://www.texify.com/img/%5CLarge%5C%21%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E2%7D%7B%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E2%2Bn%7D%7B2%7D%5Cright%29%7D%20%3D%202.gif](http://www.texify.com/img/%5CLarge%5C%21%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E2%7D%7B%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E2%2Bn%7D%7B2%7D%5Cright%29%7D%20%3D%202.gif)

Comment: why is it that as n aproaches infinity it becomes n^2 though?

Comment: This is especialy confusing because the limit as n aproachis infinity of both n, n^2 n^3, ect all = inifinty. How do you get from the equasion for finite values of n to the O nation formula

Comment: The formula for a triangle is (n^2 + n)/2. As n approaches infinity, the change in n^2 (2n) dwarfs the change in n (1), therefore we can drop the n term without changing the actual change that much in the long run.

Comment: If you want to be more precise mathematically, you show that the ratio n²/((n²+n)/2) approaches a finite, nonzero constant as n goes to infinity (divide both the numerator and denominator by n² and observe what happens); that shows that they're proportional.

Answer (score 0):

O(n^2) does not mean the operation will take n^2 steps... Only that the number of steps involved is (approximately) n^2 *times some constant value*.

In this case, your number of steps should remind you of [Gauss triangle numbers](http://math.fau.edu/richman/mla/triangle.htm). Thus, that value for `n-1` is `n*(n-1)/2`, and as for large numbers `n-1` is very close to `n`, you can approximate this value by `(n^2)/2` (and thus, the multiplication constant is 1/2).